# VlcJ Canvas on top

Tags: java, swing, awt, vlcj

I'm using the [vlcJ](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) library to play videos in my program from another `VLC` process (OutOfProcess player).  The vlcJ `Canvas` to play the video is embedded in a `Component` in a `JTabbedPane`. When the player is initialized, the video canvas comes to front on top of every other control.

I read about [heavy-/lightweight component](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html), so I know, that `JRE` 1.8 isn't still able to handle heavyweight components correctly, when drawed by another process embedded in lightweight components.

> Embedded heavyweight components must belong to the process that
>   created the frame or applet. The heavyweight component must have a
>   valid peer within the main process of the application (or applet).

So my question is how to fix this issue, so that the `Canvas` will not come to front "unasked"?

[image: vlcj canvas overlapping]
The tab "Multimedia" hosts the video canvas. Despite another tab is open, the canvas stays on top of everything. When the host tab "Multimedia" is opened once, the video canvas behavave correctly and stays in its tabs.

Comment: As you say, you simply can't. Heavy weight components don't have any concept of z-ordering

Comment: Ok, but isn't there any workaround? When i open the home tab of the video canvas once, the video canvas stays in the background. So its not impossible to get correct behaviour but before opening the ancestor tab of the video canvas the z-order is not respected.

Comment: No, there is simply no work around for this, the general rule of thumb is not to mix light and heavy weight containers.  It "might" work sometimes or under "some" conditions, but then, for no apprarent reason, it will stop working or effect other components

Comment: You could, however, add and remove the `Canvas` when ever the tab becomes selected/unselected?

Comment: I suppose you could render the video yourself using the "direct" approach rather than the "embedded" approach, with slightly worse performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @MadProgrammer and @caprica i was able to figure out a workaround: Since I'm using an OutOfProcess Player with `vlcJ-pro` i can't use the "direct" aproach, because player and canvas are not the same process.

Hide and show the video canvas is also no option, because the component, where the video images are drawn has to be visible all time (otherwise serious exception occur).

So finally i wrapped my video canvas into a `JPanel` with `CardLayout` and i switch between an empty pane and the video canvas. Every time a tab with mediaplayer is opened, the video canvas becomes visible, else the empty pane.
 This workaround seems to work fine.